# How to make a chart from multiple data sets

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart, sql-server-2014, reportbuilder

I want to make a bar chart that consists of data from multiple data sets. Is there a way to do this? The picture illustrates how I want it to look

[image]

I am querying my tabular model in SQL Server 2014 to create the data sets. I am trying to combine the queries into one data set using UNION ALL. However I am not sure how to do the union, as I have only used the query designer before and I am not very familiar with MDX. I tried just copying queries from the two datasets and doing UNION ALL between them but it did not work. I have no idea how to combine the results of two MDX queries in to one

Comment: Combine the data sets into one... You haven't provided adequate information for others to help you.

Comment: what information are you missing?

I am trying to combine the queries into one data set using union. However I am not sure how to inculde a column stating what data set the data is from. I need this for the categories in my chart

Comment: Adding the queries to your post would help. The first thing that comes to mind is possibly adding an extra column in each query that you can group on, i.e. `'DataSet1' AS DataSet`, then use  a `UNION ALL` for the next data set as you mentioned above.

Comment: SSRS does provide a way to get data from a different dataset using the LOOKUP function but I am not sure it would work in a chart report. You can try exploring that